# Emacs Org will not print out email address?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

I use Org mode on emacs 27.2 on ubuntu linux, and have for some time.  I have a template where the top section contains:

```
#+title: My title
#+author: My Name
#+date: Friday March 25 2022
#+EMAIL: myemail@somewhere.ac.uk
```

yet when I export to pdf using "Cntr X E l p"

I get this in the pdf:

```
My title
My Name
Friday March 25 2022
```

Why does it print out everything correctly except the email address?  I've tried moving it around, uppercase, lowercase and several other changes and still no joy? Thx. J.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Backends are generally free to deal with information you provide in any way they deem appropriate. That said, most of them can be guided to produce the information you tell them to process.

If you include `#+EMAIL: foo@bar.com` in your file, the exporter (code in `ox.el`) will store it in a property list (usually called `info` but it's an argument to all the functions, so its actual name does not matter). That list is passed through the various levels of the exporter, so the email information is *available* from that list under the `:email` key to everybody who wishes to use it. Whether they *choose* to use it is up to them.

In the LaTeX exporter case, the template that is produced by `org-latex-template` decides whether to use that information, based on an option setting. If you write

```
#+EMAIL: foo@bar.com
#+OPTIONS: email:t
```

in your file, then the email information *is* used: it produces the email information as a footnote attached to the author's name[1].

The list of `OPTIONS` can be found in the [Export Settings](https://orgmode.org/manual/Export-Settings.html#Export-Settings) section of the manual (available much more conveniently from within Emacs with `C-h i g(org)Export settings`), starting at about line 70 of the page (the top part of the page describes the keywords settings, like `#+EMAIL` and `#+AUTHOR`). The `email` option entry says:

> ‘email’
> Toggle inclusion of the author’s e-mail into exported file
> (‘org-export-with-email’).

so another way to set the option is to customize the variable `org-export-with-email` - that's what you should do if you *always* wanted the email to be produced (if possible of course - remember each exporter can do what it wants). You can do that by customizing the option: `C-h v org-export-with-email` and then click on the `Customize` link. Or you could add this to your init file[2]:

```el
(setq org-export-with-email t)
```

This works here because it's a simple option, but in general, customizing an option is safer because it takes care of details that might be necessary in other cases.

[1] This handling of the email address is hard-coded in the function `org-latex-template` where the string that is output is formatted on L1727 (or thereabouts) with the expression `(format "\\author{%s\\thanks{%s}}\n" author email))`. If you prefer different handling, you will unfortunately have to redefine the function to use a different form of output, but that's beyond the scope of this question.

[2] This could be `~/.emacs` or `~/.emacs.d/init.el` or `~/.config/emacs/init.el` on Linux. The actual value in your case can be found as the value of the variable `user-init-file`. See [Init file](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html) in the Emacs manual.

Comment: Thanks @NickD.  I see from searching that you have dealt with this before.  Would it not be more appropriate to have the export with email turned on by default because it is now so common/necessary?  That way if not required the author would just not include the "#+EMAIL" line ?  What file would I put the  (‘org-export-with-email’) code, perhaps my .emacs file on linux?

Comment: I added some more details on how to set the option. Let me know if that's not clear.

Comment: "... you have dealt with this before": if I did, I certainly don't remember it :-) And my search-fu failed me. Can you provide a link? If so, I'll edit appropriately.

Comment: This is where I found some stuff, but I don't know enough about lisp/emacs to make it work.  I really like Emacs, use it as my main development environment for R, Julia, SQL, etc. but don't have time to learn all of lisp.  Thx. J https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2014-02/msg00126.html

Comment: OK - I didn't realize that you were talking about the mailing list (and I certainly did not remember the situation). The ML discussion does not seem to have resulted in a definitive solution, just a suggestion on my part with no details of the implementation. But it's only tangentially related to this question and answer, so I don't think I'll be making any revisions here. If you are interested, you can ask a question on Emacs SE, although I can't guarantee I'll be able to answer it, both because of time constraints and because I might not be able to come up with one. But somebody else might.